# Org Mode syntax checker

Tags: org-mode

The correct syntax is this:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle "~/.config/emacs/init.el"
```

But once, I had, instead of `header-args`, `header-aegs`.
Notice the `e` instead of `r`.
I was getting the dreaded `tangled 0 code blocks` thingy.
It took a lot of time to find the error.
My question is:

1. How to avoid this in the future?
2. Maybe there is some kind of syntax checker? Maybe `flycheck`? Maybe there is an Org Mode LSP implementation?

Comment: `header-aegs` is a legal property name, so syntax checkers are not going to help. You need a heuristic checker of some sort: perhaps one that checks property names to see if they are "one step away" from one in a predefined set. If something like that exists (and I don't know either way), `org-lint` might be a good place to add it.